Bluetooth printer project - Failed to resolve: io.paperdb:paperdb:2.7.1
Hi i m getting this error:

Failed to resolve: io.paperdb:paperdb:2.7.1
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6.

After following this tutorial to do Bluetooth printing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6azeYSRgoQ
Without any link to get this error library.
implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.7.1'

I have not used this library, I have already cleaned, rebuilt and eliminated invalidate caches.
They tell me to add Paper.init(this); in onCreate method, how do you do it?
It makes sense?
This is all i get on my Logcat.

This is a build problem, so it won’t be solved by modifying onCreate. Please include relevant gradle files to help identify the problem.

I can leave the :
Grandle App
'implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.mazenrashed:Printooth:1.2.1''
Grandle Project
'repositories {
maven {
url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
}
google()
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
maven { url "https://artifactory.img.ly/artifactory/imgly" }
}'

In order to fix the issue, I updated the project's dependencies in build.gradle by changing:
implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.7.1'

to:
implementation 'io.github.pilgr:paperdb:2.7.2'

Fortunately, the import statements remain the same:
import io.paperdb.Book;
import io.paperdb.Paper;

